# Healenium driver unable to launch application url in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, healenium

**I was initialised healenium(self-healing) driver in my project. When i am tring to execute code, chrome browser is launching but it is not able to launch  application url.**

*Error i was getting:
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.